# Add Profile picture to Django Custom User model(AbstractUser)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-users

I have used a custom user model to overwrite username with email-id. Now I want to add an extra field that profiles pictures. I tried extending the model in models.py with the OnetoOne relationship. It works but as I am passing forms to update and create views (Class-based views) to update and create.

is there any way to add a profile picture field without creating a model with the OnetoOne relationship?

SOLUTION:

I was missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this will helps you, check my github code... i`m using image field in User model.

> https://github.com/shotttik/carwashProject/blob/master/user/models.py

#models.py

```
 class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        ....
        def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
            extra_fields.setdefault('image', "default/image/path")
        ...


    class User(AbstractUser):
        ....
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

then you can add image field into forms.py

Comment: Thank you shotiko, I did add some lines taking your code as a reference. But when I upload a new image while registering, it doesn't get saved. the default image is used always. Even when I use update view, the uploaded image does not reflect. Any solutions? I have updated my code please check

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. i think you have problem inside views.py do you can show me code? Ty

Comment: Please check, i have updated my views in my question

Comment: hey, maybe i found solution. in your class based views  you should write like that - form_class = ProfileForm(rrequest.POST, request.FILES) . please check this and reply...

Comment: Thank you Shotiko, The problem was in the form tag. I was missing enctype="multipart/form-data". Thank you for your time