# How can I add an Image to a Django Custom User Model (AbstractUser)?

Tags: python, django, image, vue.js

I am trying to add 'image' to a class that extends AbstractUser. I would like to know how I could use fetch api to make a post request (vuejs) so that it calls on an views.py api and specifically uploads an image for a user.

I understand how this would work when it comes to frontend but I do not know what my django views.py api would do assuming I only want it to take a file object and just add to the appropriate user.

I have followed the below tutorial, however, they assume DRF is being used as opposed to an api simply made in views.py. This is why I am unsure about what my api will need to do with the image object I pass over using formData https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tpMG6btI1Q

I have seen the below SO post but it does not directly address what my views.py api would do. That is, will it just store an image in a certain format? A URL?

[Add Profile picture to Django Custom User model(AbstractUser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499538/add-profile-picture-to-django-custom-user-modelabstractuser)

```
class CUser(AbstractUser):    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you want to upload an image(in the process of creating a user) in an async manner. The followings are general settings and codes to upload an image and save an model instance.

First, You need to install pillow to use ImageField

```bash
pip install pillow
```

And create 'media' folder to save uploaded images(same level in manage.py)

**settings.py**

In Djnago, you need to specify where to save an image.

> I have seen the below SO post but it does not directly address what my
> views.py api would do. That is, will it just store an image in a
> certain format? A URL?

MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL both are needed, one is for internal usage(storing images in server) and the other is for user

```py
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'       # trailing slash is needed.
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**models.py**

ImageTest is a model to test uploading an image. You can use this in your CUser with a little adjustment.

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ImageTest(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar')   # uploaded photo saved in MEDIA_ROOT/avatar/
                                                    # ex) media/avatar/pic.jpg
```

**admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ImageTest

class ImageTestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('image',)
    list_display = ['id', 'image']

admin.site.register(ImageTest, ImageTestAdmin)
```

**views.py**

create-user is a view for serving upload form to user, and ajax-create-user is a handler for saving an image and an ImageTest instance.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ImageTest
# Create your views here.

def create_user(request):
    context = {'msg':'upload image'}
    return render(request, 'templates/upload.html', context)
    
def ajax_create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = ImageTest(image=request.FILES['avatar'])
        user.save()
    return HttpResponse('uploading image success')
```

**upload.html**

A template for rendering upload form. Write your vuejs codes here.

```html
{{msg}}

<form action="{% url 'ajax-create-user' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/*">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

Let's connect views and urls.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from anthony import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('anthony/', views.create_user, name='create-user'),
    path('anthony/ajax-create-user', views.ajax_create_user, name='ajax-create-user'),
]

# for development environment(no needed in production)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Summary**

1. An image is passed to views via html form.
2. Views can access that image in request.FILES(or request.POST)
3. Assign an image to Model field, and save the instance. Both are saved automatically.